# NSXMLParser cannot parse from local file

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

I want to parse data from local xml file and populate a table view with the information from the file. I added schedule.xml file into my project, and wrote this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("scheduleFile", ofType: "xml")
    let url:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlpath!)
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()

    let success: Bool = parser.parse()

    print(success)
}
```

I thought I have problems with my table view, but then I added print(success) and realized that I am not parsing any data. Log gives false. Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit

class ClassListTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var classList: [Class] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("scheduleFile", ofType: "xml")
        let url:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlpath!)
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()

        let success: Bool = parser.parse()

        print(success)
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
  }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return classList.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClassCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let oneClass: Class = classList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = oneClass.name

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: - NSXMLParserDelegate methods

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

        Class().eName = elementName
        if elementName == "task" {
            Class().name = String()
        }   
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let data = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        if (!data.isEmpty) {
            if Class().eName == "title" {
                Class().name += data
                print(Class().name)
            }
        }    
    }  

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "task" {
            let oneClass: Class = Class()
            oneClass.name = Class().name
            //oneClass.image = image
            classList.append(oneClass)
        }
    } 
}
```

Classes here are Math, History, etc. Don't be confused.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `scheduleFile.xml` is a valid XML file?

Comment: It actually can see there are two <tasks> but Log gives "false".